# how to keep css style by using vue

Tags: javascript, html, css, vuejs2, vue-router

I am learning vue and trying to build a website by using vue. And I set two navigation tabs in navigation bar.

Here is the router config file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Management from '@/components/Management'
import Execution from '@/components/Execution'

Vue.use(Router)

const router = new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      redirect: { name: 'Management'}
    },
    {
      path: '/management/list',
      name: 'Management',
      component: Management,
    },
    {
      path: '/execution/list',
      name: 'Execution',
      component: Execution
    }
  ]
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  next();
})

export default router
```

And App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="header">
        <ul class="nav-ul">
            <router-link tag="li" :class="['nav-li', {active: show === 'management'}]" v-on:click="changeShow('management')" :to="{name: 'Management'}"><span>case management</span></router-link>
            <router-link tag="li" :class="['nav-li', {active: show === 'execution'}]" v-on:click="changeShow('execution')" :to="{name: 'Execution'}"><span>case execution</span></router-link>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function(){
    return {
      show: 'management'
    }
  },
  computed: {
    changeShow: function (show) {
        this.show = show;
    }
  },
  watch: {
    '$route'(to, from) {
      if (to.name) {
        this.show = to.name.toLowerCase()
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
  .container {
    height: 100%;
  }
  #header {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#FF3300 0,#ff6600 20%);
  }
  .nav-ul,.nav-li 
  {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
  }
  .nav-ul 
  {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .nav-li {
    width: 100px; 
    height: 38px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 12px;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  .nav-li:hover {
    background-color: #FFCC00;
    cursor:pointer;
  }
  .nav-li.active {
    background-color: #FFCC00;
  }
</style>
```

When I click the `execution` tab, it is expected that the background color of it is changed to #FFCC00 (tab class is `nav-li active`) and browser url is `/execution/list`. However, after I refresh the page, the class of `management` tab is `nav-li active` and background color is #FFCC00 while the url is still `/execution/list`. Why does the class of `management` tab become `nav-li active` while class of `execution` tab is `nav-li`?

Comment: try adding "scoped" prop to your style tag , <style scoped>

Comment: Have you considered just modifying active route css classes like router-link-active? It does the mapping of active route for you.
More here: https://router.vuejs.org/api/#active-class

Comment: adding "scoped" is not working

Comment: adding router-link-active css style is working, but I still wonder why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running a `watch` property on `$route` and it works fine when there's a change in the route. But when you refresh, the route doesn't change hence the underline watch never gets triggered.
Create a `mounted` function and check for route name there and modify your `show` data accordingly. Something like this should work:

```
mounted(){
    this.show = this.$route.name.toLowerCase();
}
```